# dircolor mistakes caused by the permission of ntfs-3g

Tags: debian, ls, colors, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I am using `dircolor-solarized` to render my `ls` output. It works well in my linux partition. However, in a NTFS partition mounted by ntfs-3g, all the files were colored green [image: green] because `/etc/fstab` grants the executable permission to the partition:

```
/dev/sdb5   /mnt/win10_E    ntfs-3g     rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0022,fmask=0033  0   0
```

and in my `dircolors.256dark` there is:

```
EXEC 00;38;5;64
```

I have tried `umask=0022` but the output keeps the same. Actually I don't think things will change if executable permission is granted to any of the users. But when I tried 'umask=0111', the partition just failed to be mounted. So I am here to ask for a help:

1) Is there any way to mount a ntfs partation writable and readable, while executable permission is absent?

2) If 1) is not possible in ntfs-3g, is there a way to lower the priority of EXEC rendering? For example, let dircolor firstly match the extension names, and then EXEC if no match found in the list.

3) Any other workaround?

My distribution:

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian-Z620 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u3 (2016-07-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks!

Comment: What was the exact command used, and error message shown, when the partition "failed to be mounted"?  `-o fmask=111` works for me (kernel 3.13.0-92-generic #139-Ubuntu, ntfs-3g 1:2013.1.13AR.1-2ubuntu2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @jigglynaga, you can get part of what you want using a different mount option.

According to the manual page, these are the relevant options:

> **`umask`**=*value*
> Set the bitmask of the file and directory permissions that are not present. The value is given in octal. The default value is **0** which means full access to everybody.
>
> **`fmask`**=*value*
> Set the bitmask of the file permissions that are not present. The value is given in octal. The default value is **0** which means full access to everybody.
>
> **`dmask`**=*value*
> Set the bitmask of the directory permissions that are not present. The value is given in octal. The default value is **0** which means full access to everybody.

You were using **`umask`**, which applies to both files and directories.  But since you need executable permissions on directories, and disallowed this, the driver did not cooperate.  Changing that to **`fmask`** affects only *files*.

Just in case, you might want to review the `dmask` setting as well (full access to everybody may not be what you want).

As for `ls` (and `dircolors`).  No: the `ls` program checks for `EXEC` before checking any pattern, so you could not make a special case with a pattern such as `*.exe`

That is not well documented; you can read the source code to see

- [attribute-checks](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c#n4383) and later
- [pattern-checks](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c#n4429) (if no attribute was applicable).
- [ntfs-3g - Third Generation Read/Write NTFS Driver](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.ntfs-3g)

Comment: Yes, you're right. The executable permission of directories cannot be removed, or I cannot access browse the partition with a non-root user. So I choose `dmask=0022,fmask=0111` this time, and everything goes well :-) @JigglyNaga Thank you all the same!